# React Native 0.68.2 application running issues

Tags: android, ios, react-native, metro-bundler, reactotron

I am stuck with running my application using React Native version 0.68.2.
Suddenly, the application stopped responding to the JavaScript code changes (hot reload) - I've checked and the option is "on". Also, the console logs are not visible anymore in the console and the simulator does not connect to the Reactotron. Same case for both iOS and Android. I can build and run the application but the Axios also do not work.
Different application with almost identical configurations but running React Native version 0.66 working great.
I've tried to reset the cache for Metro (npx react-native start --reset-cache).
No errors or warnings are shown while I start the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem is, but try to clean anything

Delete your project folder in `/Users/{YOUR_USERNAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
and run to clean all:

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -f podfile.lock && rm -rf node_modules && yarn &&  cd ios && pod install && cd .. && yarn start --reset-cache
```

I hope it can help you!

Comment: I've tried all of this and it didn't help... The weirdest thing is that I can not see the output of the console.log()...

Comment: try to run your app with Xcode, maybe you will see some errors here

Comment: Tried this too. Nothing unusual. Compared it to other application that I've run via Xcode too. For now, my solution is to create a new project, and copy all of the code and dependencies - I don't know why but it works.